# How to update the array in the react native?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native

How to update the array by changing one of the objects?

This will be my array code

```
this.datas = [
    {
        index: 1,
        name: 'Tony',
        status: 'Absent',
        reason: null
    },
    {
        index: 2,
        name: 'Chris',
        status: 'Present',
        reason: null
    },
];
```

So now i want to write a function to update the reason like {reason: any reason} which from the index 1, index 2 remain the same.

So Far i had tried these

```
setReason = reason => {

let data = [...this.state.nameList];
let ind = data.findIndex(el => el.index === 'number');
data[ind] = { ...data[ind], reason: reason };
this.setState({
  nameList: data
});
};
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: You can use [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to pick the object by `index`, then simply set `.reason`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update a single object data of an array
You need to first know the index of the object in the array which you want to update
eg Want to update first object of array

```
this.datas[0].reason = 'My custom reason';
```

Now you want to update the object of an array by finding the object in array you have to add a loop in it
eg:  Update reason where name = Chris

```
for(i=0; i<this.datas.length; i++){
    if(this.datas[i].name=='Chris'){
        this.datas[i].reason = 'My custom reason';
     break;
    }  
}
```

Comment: Didn't get your point. After data is updated the updated data will be available in the same array. if any state is need to updated then use setState({})

Answer (score 1):

you can use `map` function on array.

```
let data =  [
    {
        index: 1,
        name: 'Tony',
        status: 'Absent',
        reason: null
    },
    {
        index: 2,
        name: 'Chris',
        status: 'Present',
        reason: null
    },
];
data = data.map(obj=>{
    return{
    ...obj,
    reason: 'any reason',
}
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `of` in the `for` loop and update the property value in an array, this is the working solution of your question.

```js
var datas = [
    {
        index: 1,
        name: 'Tony',
        status: 'Absent',
        reason: null
    },
    {
        index: 2,
        name: 'Chris',
        status: 'Present',
        reason: null
    },
];

for(data of datas){
    data["reason"] = "any reason";
}

console.log(datas);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
var datas = [
    {
        index: 1,
        name: 'Tony',
        status: 'Absent',
        reason: null
    },
    {
        index: 2,
        name: 'Chris',
        status: 'Present',
        reason: null
    },
];
datas.map(data=> data.reason ="my reason");
console.log(datas)
```